# Nextjs Head tag converts & sign to &amp; in meta and link tag

Tags: next.js, seo

Let's suppose I have this component.

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

export const Index: React.FC = () => {
  const myUrl = `https://example.com/books/filter/authorName='DavidJames'&inStock=true`;
  return (
    <Head>
      <link rel='canonical' href={myUrl} />
      <meta property='og:url' content={myUrl} />
    </Head>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

You can see that the url contains a `&` sign.
When I click `View page source` I see that the `&` sign is converted to `&amp;`, so the final url looks like this `https://example.com/books/filter/authorName='DavidJames'&amp;inStock=true`.

But doing so, the link is partially broken, only first filter will be correctly parsed by backend code.

How to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** I noticed that this issue only happens for development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double quotes instead of backticks on the url?

```
const myUrl = "https://example.com/books/filter/authorName='DavidJames'&inStock=true"
```

Maybe also try adding a backslash before the `&` character like so

```
const myUrl = `https://example.com/books/filter/authorName='DavidJames'\&inStock=true`
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that you suggested works, Nextjs renders `<meta property="test" content="&amp;"/>` instead of `<meta property="test" content="&"/>`

"next": "12.3.0",